# How to get variables of batch_normalization's mean and variance in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

guys.

If you will implement Batch normalization in Tensorflow, it should be the following program.

```
def batchnorm_forward(X, gamma, beta):
mu = np.mean(X, axis=0)
var = np.var(X, axis=0)

X_norm = (X - mu) / np.sqrt(var + 1e-8)
out = gamma * X_norm + beta

cache = (X, X_norm, mu, var, gamma, beta)

return out, cache, mu, var
```

At this time,

In order to inference at inference-phase only, it should save variables (mean, variance) as follows.

```
# BatchNorm training forward propagation
h2, bn2_cache, mu, var = batchnorm_forward(h2, gamma2, beta2)
bn_params['bn2_mean'] = .9 * bn_params['bn2_mean'] + .1 * mu
bn_params['bn2_var'] = .9 * bn_params['bn2_var'] + .1 * var
```

In this inference-phase only, it uses the following program.

```
# BatchNorm inference forward propagation
h2 = (h2 - bn_params['bn2_mean']) / np.sqrt(bn_params['bn2_var'] + 1e-8)
h2 = gamma2 * h2 + beta2
```

In Tensorflow, How to get variables (raw value) of the "bn_params['bn2_mean']" and "bn_params['bn2_var']" ?

```
with tf.name_scope('fc1'):
  w1  = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 16, 32])
  h1 = tf.matmul(pool_flat2,  w1)
  fc1_bn = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(inputs = h1, is_training = phase_train)
  fc1_bn_relu = tf.nn.relu(fc1_bn)
  ...
  ...
...
...
# ????? how to get variables ?????
# Image in my head
mean, var = fc1_bn.eval()
```

help me :<

ref: https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/07/04/batchnorm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the object-oriented version of the Layer. Then it's as easy as accessing properties of the object:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> bn = tf.layers.BatchNormalization()
>>> bn(tf.ones([1, 3]))
<tf.Tensor 'batch_normalization/batchnorm/add_1:0' shape=(1, 3) dtype=float32>
>>> bn.variables
[<tf.Variable 'batch_normalization/gamma:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'batch_normalization/beta:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'batch_normalization/moving_mean:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>, <tf.Variable 'batch_normalization/moving_variance:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>]
>>> bn.moving_mean
<tf.Variable 'batch_normalization/moving_mean:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>
>>> bn.moving_variance
<tf.Variable 'batch_normalization/moving_variance:0' shape=(3,) dtype=float32_ref>
>>>
```

Comment: What should I do in order to know the attributes such as tf.layers.BarchNormalization()?

Comment: I seem that text in Tensorflow is not written

Comment: [`Layer.variables` is documented](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/BatchNormalization#variables) at least. I got those two properties by [skimming the code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cbc658095ae228f2f557af47e4901d552573aa15/tensorflow/python/layers/normalization.py#L306), but you could also use Python's built-in `dir()` after the `Layer` has been built/called.

Answer (score 0):

The object-oriented version tf.layers.BatchNormalization() is dangerous since it has no initial parameter training=True/False. You have to apply it like

```
bn_instance = tf.layers.BatchNormalization(trainable=True)
batch_layer = bn_instance.apply(input,training=True)
```

Otherwise it will use the initial moving_mean(=0)/moving_variance(=1) to normalize the data during training. (Which is supposed to be used only at inference)